# Download mega.nz file from command line

Tags: mega

I have a mega public URL, and I want to download it in the command line ubuntu, the file is 5 GB.
thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the commands `curl` and/or `wget` ...

Comment: @SorenA tools like curl, wget, aria2, axel, etc are not able to download from mega.

Comment: Please edit your question and add whether you want to download a shared file or a file stored at mega.nz but not shared.

Answer (score 6):

Install [`megatools`](https://megatools.megous.com/):

```
sudo apt install megatools
```

Use `megadl` to download your file:

```
megadl 'https://mega.nz/your-public-url'
```